# exporting from R objects of class "gts" "hts"

Tags: r, forecasting, excel

I am trying to save my forecast of class "gts" "hts" from R into excel but I get an error in R - "cannot coerce class "c("gts", "hts")" to a data.frame".
Thank you,
Despina

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it focuses on routine operations within statistical computing platform and it does not have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
library(hts)
fc <- forecast(htseg1, h = 10, method = "bu", fmethod = "arima")
fcdf <- as.data.frame(allts(fc))
write.table(fcdf, file="forecasts.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```